# BackboneJs understandable Json Format for Json Parse

Tags: json, backbone.js

I have two type of JSON format one is with a single data, another one is with multiple data in an array of JSON.

First JSON format:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "1",
    "artist": "Gotye",
    "title": "Making  Mirrors"
}
```

}

Second:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "artist": "Gotye",
        "title": "Making  Mirrors"
    },
    {
        "id": "99",
        "artist": "uy",
        "title": "uy"
    },
    {
        "id": "100",
        "artist": "yt",
        "title": "yt"
    },
    {
        "id": "101",
        "artist": "65",
        "title": "565"
    },
    {
        "id": "102",
        "artist": "6",
        "title": "6"
    },
    {
        "id": "103",
        "artist": "y",
        "title": "yy"
    },
    {
        "id": "104",
        "artist": "ty",
        "title": "yt"
    }
    ]
}
```

In backbone model when I do:

> parse: function(response) {
>               return response.data;
>           }

for the first one, it works which i can populate the JSON data to the view, but for the second JSON it does not.

I am wondering if there is any way that could make the backbone parse function to standardize the JSON format to backbone understadable format. Any advice or any solution for this will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is your `parse` in a model or a collection? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: the parse is in the model. doesn't work means the parsed data does not populate in the view. I have edited the question. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Attach model view at least plus piece of code u pass model to view

Comment: @muistooshort, I got the idea now. I should add it into collection instead of model. Thanks a lot.